# HoughLinesP using trackbar

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am doing edge detection using HoughLinesP opencv function. I wanted to get an estimation of good values for the parameters of this function using trackbars. I have the following code:

```
def compute_edgelets(image):

   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   global edges
   edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)


   init_thresh = 50
   max_thresh = 1000
   init_min_line = 10
   max_min_line = 1000
   init_max_line = 1
   max_max_line = 100

   cv2.namedWindow("Result")
   cv2.createTrackbar("threshold", "Result", init_thresh, max_thresh, on_change)
   cv2.createTrackbar("min", "Result", init_min_line, max_min_line, on_change)
   cv2.createTrackbar("max", "Result", init_max_line, max_max_line, on_change)

   while True:
       cv2.imshow("Result", image)
       key = cv2.waitKey(1)
       if key == ord('q'):
           break
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

on_change function:

```
def on_change(x):

   threshold = cv2.getTrackbarPos("threshold", "Result")
   min_line_length = cv2.getTrackbarPos("min", "Result")
   max_line_gap = cv2.getTrackbarPos("max", "Result")

   lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold, min_line_length, max_line_gap)
   for x in range(0, len(lines)):
       for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
           cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

However, this code does not work as intented - the arguments do not seem to work correctly and after changing the values on a trackbar for a little bit I get the following TypeError:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Is there something I am doing wrong with the trackbars?

Comment: Apparently the combination of parameters (which you don't tell us) you had selected at that moment with the image (which you don't show us) results in `HoughLinesP` not finding anything, and it signals this by returning `None`. Your code doesn't account for this scenario.  At least I guess (you omitted the backtrace), but that's the only place I see `len` used.

Comment: @DanMašek Exactly. Your comment should an answer.

Comment: @karlphillip Alright, if you say so .. didn't really seem worth it, plus I'm kinda demotivated lately. BTW, love that most recent comment, couldn't be more eloquent :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to tell you the exact reason why this is happening (as you didn't provide all the relevant data to reproduce this exact issue), but fortunately the root issue is easy to pinpoint.

The error refers to a call to `len` and the only place this is used in the sample code is getting the length of the result of [`cv2.HoughLinesP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb). The issue is that you're trying to take a length of `None`, which doesn't make sense.

In Python, when you call `cv2.HoughLinesP` with a set of parameters that prohibit it from finding any lines, it will return `None` instead of a sequence of line parameters you can iterate over. We can easily demonstrate a few of such situations:

- Process empty image:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  print cv2.HoughLinesP(None, 1, np.pi/180, 50, 10, 1)
  ```

  Outputs `None`
- Process an all-black image:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  print cv2.HoughLinesP(np.zeros((100,100,1), np.uint8), 1, np.pi/180, 50, 10, 1)
  ```

  Outputs `None`

In your example code, you do not handle such scenario, and you directly try to get the length of the result. Since you can't apply `len` on `None`, you get an error. Hence, you need to do some adjustments to your code ... at the least something like

```
if lines is None:
     return
```